# constrain a generic class further in one of its member functions c#

Tags: c#, oop, generics

Inexperienced with generics here. Am I able to constrain a method's type more than its class constraint if it's further down its type heirarchy?

Here's what I tried (BotAccountDetailsBase derives from AccountDetailsBase):

```
  public class SafeOffer<TAcc> where TAcc : AccountDetailsBase
  {
    public readonly TAcc account_;
    public readonly List<ItemData> items_;

    private SafeOffer(TAcc account, List<ItemData> items)
    {
      account_ = account;
      items_ = items;
    }

    public static List<SafeOffer<TAcc>> DivideOffer<TBot>(IEnumerable<BotAccountDetailsBase> accounts, List<ItemData> items) where TBot : BotAccountDetailsBase
    {
      var accounts_to_trade = new List<SafeOffer<TBot>>();

      // get the bots of the right type, order by slots
      var typed_account = accounts.OfType<TBot>().OrderByDescending(x => x.slotsleft_);

      foreach (var acc in typed_account)
      {
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
          var bundle = items.Take(acc.slotsleft_);
          items.RemoveAll(x => bundle.Contains(x));
          var offer = new SafeOffer<TBot>(acc, bundle.ToList());
          accounts_to_trade.Add(offer);
        }
      }
      return accounts_to_trade;
    }
  }
```

Since TAcc and TBot are not the same it does not compile. is there some magic cast I can use?

Comment: Could you create an example that compiles (or not) by itself, and doesn't depend on lots of classes not posted here? I would be interested in tinkering with the code but I'm not going to create all the missing classes. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Comment: Do you really need generics in this case? Arent' the Bases enough for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the return type to `List<SafeOffer<TBot>>`:

```
public static List<SafeOffer<TBot>> 
    DivideOffer<TBot>(IEnumerable<BotAccountDetailsBase> accounts, List<ItemData> items) 
        where TBot : BotAccountDetailsBase
```

Comment: I swear I attempted this :)